# Windows 10 Set up on New Hard Drive - Wants GPT and NTFS but reformats to MBR and Fat32 when adding software to hard drive

Tags: windows-10

I have cleaned and formatted my 2T Seagate BarraCuda several times now to match what Windows System asks for on boot (GPT, NTFS on EFI).

Then I use the Windows 10 Download to create new installation media and it reformats the drive to an MBR and FAT32. I have no idea how to stop this, and when I install and go to boot, it asks for GPT and NTFS.

HELP! How do I install Windows 10 from the software download available on a new hard drive?

Comment: Do you want to install Windows on this drive or use it as installation media to install on another drive?

Comment: Yes I want it installed, it will be a new internal hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

The tool doesn't install Windows directly. It puts a Windows installer on the drive that you're supposed to use to have Windows installed.

Prepare a USB flash drive (at least 8 GB) and make sure you don't have any important data on it, because it will be formatted. Use the Windows 10 Download Tool from Microsoft (or [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) - an unofficial alternative) to put the installer on it. The tool from Microsoft will prepare a universal installer, while Rufus will make one suited specifically for MBR or GPT mode depending on your choice.

Then boot off that flash drive in UEFI mode and select the internal 2TB drive to install Windows on it. Windows will automatically convert it to GPT.

If the drive is still getting set up as MBR, it means that you're booting in BIOS mode (aka legacy mode) rather than UEFI mode.

Answer (score -1):

I changed-out and cloned my HDD to SSD using Macrium Reflect, a cloning prg that needs zero BIAS work by the user and W10 accepts the cloned drive without fuss.
Info on how to install using MR can be found on utube.

Comment: This does not answer the question.